# open only new terminal window in custom directory

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm opening the terminal by pressing `Window + 2`. I want that to open in `~/some-custom-directory`

Thing is, I want **new tabs** within the terminal window to NOT be affected by this behavior, i.e. if I'm in `~/other-directory` and open a new tab, I want it to open in the same directory `~/other-directory`, and not default to `~/some-custom-directory`

Is this possible?
Can I change the behavior of opening a terminal window without it affecting opening a terminal tab?

Comment: I don’t think you can do that with a single key combination. However you should be able to do it with two different key combinations. e.g. Windows+2 for the custom directory and some other combination for a new tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already works like you wish by default.

- You can specify a different startup directory with the option `--working-directory`, e.g. `gnome-terminal --working-directory ~/some-custom-directory`
- When you open a new tab, the new tab will always default to the current directory of the active tab, i.e., if you are in `~/other-directory`, a new tab will also open in `~/other-directory`.

To have that work for the shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, which launches or switches to the application that is the 2nd favorite on your dock (in your case, that is the terminal), edit the `.desktop` launcher involved.

- Copy the desktop launcher of Gnome terminal (`/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` to your local `applications` directory (`~/.local/share/applications`).
- Edit that local copy of the `.desktop` file and add the option to the command in the `Exec=` line. *Note that here, you need to indicate the full path name, because bash expansion (`~`) or variable substitution (e.g. `$HOME`) does not work in `.desktop` launchers.* The customized copy will take precedence over the default one, so within seconds, your shortcut key should launch your terminal in the directory of your choice (of course, only if Terminal was not running - if it is running, the shortcut key will only bring the running instance forward without changing directories).

Comment: `--working-directory ~/some-custom-directory` didn't work, neither did `--working-directory $HOME/some-custom-directory`, what did work is `--working-directory /home/MY_USER_NAME/some-custom-directory`. Change your answer to that and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Indeed, bash expansion does not work in .desktop launchers. I added a warning for those unaware.